# Best way of monitoring exports from AWS DynamoDB to the S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to add any monitoring of exports from AWS DynamoDB to the S3 bucket. I tried to find any AWS Cloudwatch metrics or logs related to exports but didn't spot any. I'm using the ExportTableToPointInTime method to trigger the export.

My goal is to create the AWS Cloudwatch alarm in case of any errors. I would like also to verify the number of successful/failed exports. Currently, after some investigation, I have in mind creating the AWS Lambda that fetches (once per hour) the number of exports and validates if all were successful.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are no metrics for exports out of the box. You're on the right track by polling the status of each export.

You can do this quicker than 1 hour, as you are simply listing and describing exports, which incurs no cost. You would only pay for the Lambda invocations.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you know if AWS has plans to introduce such a metric in the near future?

Comment: I'm not aware of any plans sorry, but I'll be sure to pass on your feedback.